# Esperanto word for a "seed" (for a random number generator)

Tags: single-word-requests

ENGLISH

I am looking for a good, brief translation for a *seed* in a random number generator. This [seed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_seed) is the input given to such a generator that then determines its output, usually in an unpredictable way. If you start with the same seed, you end up with the same 'random' sequence of numbers.

So far for my Slay the Spire translation I translated this awkwardly with something like "komenca valoro por la generilo", but I need a shorter translation now. French just calls it *graine*, so perhaps *greno* could work in the same figurative sense? But I would want to stick to an existing translation, should it exist (even though I couldn't find it, I even checked Komputeko).

---

ESPERANTO

Mi serĉas bonan, mallongan tradukon por *seed* en generilo de hazardaj valoroj. Ĉi tiu *seed* estas la enigo por tia generilo, kiu estigas ties eligon, kutime en neantaŭvidebla maniero. Se oni komencas per la sama *seed*, oni ricevas la saman 'hazardan' sekvencon de valoroj.

Ĝisnune por mia traduko de Slay the Spire, mi tradukis tion iom malelegante: proksimume "komenca valoro por la generilo", sed nun mi bezonas malpli longan tradukon. La franca nomas tion tre simple *graine*, do eble *greno* taŭgus simile figurasence? Tamen mi volas sekvi ekzistantan tradukon, se tio jam ekzistas (kvankam mi ne povus trovi ĝin, mi eĉ kontrolis Komputekon).

Comment: I've got no sourced answer but commenting to follow... "Seed" (in English) is no less figurative than "grain". So I think either of those would work (semo, grajno - note that greno refers to grain or cereal as a concept, as in "wheat is a grain crop"). I also imagine "fonto" (source) would also make sense.

Comment: Exactly, and I believe several other languages also make use of the same metaphor/figurative language. "Semilla" in Spanish, "semente" in Portuguese, "بذرة" in Arabic (had to look those up, but they all mean "seed"). You're right that "semo" might make more sense than "greno", good shout.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Mi serĉis kaj nenion trovis en kvar vortaroj kaj terminaroj: PIV, Matematika Vortaro de Bavant (2003), Matematika Vortaro Esperanta-Ĉeĥa de Werner (1990), Matematika kaj Stokastika Terminaro Esperanta de Reiersøl (1987). Mi trovis neniun artikolon, kiu reale parolus pri generiloj por hazardnombroj.

La rekta traduko *(hazarda) semo* aŭ *semnombro* estas tamen tiom facile komprenebla metaforo, ke mi rekomendas uzi ĝin. Ankaŭ en aliaj lingvoj oni uzas similajn vortojn (*graine, semilla*), kaj se oni ion scias pri la koncernaj algoritmoj, oni tuj komprenas la vorton. En teksto por nesciantoj oni devas, ĉiuokaze, en la komenco iom klarigi la aferon per aliaj vortoj. Simple parolu pri *semo*.

Certe, eblas trovi ankaŭ aliajn taŭgajn esprimojn, ekzemple kombinaĵojn kun *start-*, *startiga*, aŭ *komenca* (*nombro aŭ valoro*).

Kiel diris Shayne Power, *greno* ne taŭgas, ĉar ĝi havas kolektivan sencon. *Grajno* povas signifi unu semon aŭ alian etan objekton, sed ĝi estas neniam uzata kiel verbo, dum *semi* estas taŭga por signifoj kiel  *estigi, komenci, ekkreskigi*.

Comment: Bone, dankon! Mi ja volas aldoni, ke mi ne certas, ĉu 'semnombro' tute taŭgas, ĉar ĉi tia 'semo' ne ĉiam estas nombro. Normale estas iu signoĉeno, kiu povas enhavi kaj numerojn kaj literojn (aŭ eĉ aliajn signojn). Krom tio, mi pensas, ke via rekomendo estas tre bona.